# Eliminating the $xy$ term of an equation for a conic gives $\tan 2\beta = 2/0$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

So, I have the following :

> $$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 2\sqrt{2}\;x - 2\sqrt{2}\;y+4=0$$

I know that to take out the $xy$ term from $A x^2 + B x y + C y^2 + \cdots = 0$, I must use : 
$$\tan 2\beta=\frac{B}{A-C}$$

But the problem is that I get 
$$\tan 2\beta =\frac{2}{0}$$

What should I do ?

Comment: If $\tan 2a = \frac{2}{0}$, what is $a$?

Comment: I did an edit sorry

Comment: That wasn't my point. If $\tan 2\beta = \frac{2}{0}$, then what is $2\beta$? (What angle has a tangent of $\infty$?) So, what is $\beta$?

Comment: Well there is pi/4 ? Because after it gives pi/2

Comment: Yes, exactly. So if $\beta = \pi/4$, you can define $x'$ and $y'$ and do the rotation.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work. Look here pls : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521267/reducing-an-equation-in-two-variables?noredirect=1#comment3098038_1521267

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$, not sure what $a$, $A$, $B$, and $C$ are in this case..

Comment: I did an edit. a is $\beta$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan2\beta=\dfrac{2}{0}$ is infinity, then $\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Get to parabola $B^2-4AC=4-4=0$, the rotation is

$$x=\dfrac{x'}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$y=\dfrac{x'}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{y'}{\sqrt{2}}$$

With focal axis $y=-x$

Comment: Is it normal that it takes me so much time to calculate when I replace it in the equation with all the cos, sin etc ?

Comment: It depends on the skill. A little late but the accounts do get the problem

Comment: Wait, are you saying that after I get xy out, I get a parabola ?

Comment: Hey I got x^2 / 4 plus 1 does this make sense ?